# Clock mechanism

Tags: java, timezone, logic, clock

I've been trying to make a timezone calculator, and I have problems going from 0h to 24h and vice-versa. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //this is for something else in the main method
import java.time.Clock;

public class TmzCalc extends Thread
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
//skipping some useless code
TmzCalc.hst(int hr); //the integer is declared inside main, and used by the 
hst method
}

public static void hst(int hr)
{
int x = hr - 10;
if(hr < 0){
   hr = 24;
};
     System.out.println("Honolulu-HST :: " + x);
}
```

Now here's the problem: if i say the hr is 2, then it will print -8, what i actually want it to print is 16. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Read the code carefully, check your variable names

Comment: A [mcve] would be much easier to help you with. (This code wouldn't compile.) But fundamentally, you've said that *any* value less than 0 should end up as 24. So -1, -2 etc would all end up as 24. Shouldn't they be 23, 22 etc? Think about how to achieve that relation. And then also look at when you're using `x` and when you're using `hr`.

Comment: Can you give me a hint? Should i use a for loop? I mean, sure, i can set some rules with a lot of lines but i wanna save the hassle. I'm pretty new in java...

Comment: I think this is a fine exercise for you, I don’t want to say you shouldn’t do it, but for any readers needing time zone conversion for production code: use the built-in `ZoneId` class and friends, don’t roll your own conversion.

Comment: @D.M. This could be a good time for you to learn to use your debugger. There could be additional help [here: How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).